# PLSQL convert single row in one string

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I'm looking for a Oracle function for convert all record of one row in a single string

TABLE_A

|a|b|c|1|

|d|e|f|2|

|g|h|i|3|

```
select * from TABLE_A where COL4='1';
```

must return

"abc"

```
select * from TABLE_A where COL4='2';
```

"def"

**I can't use CONCAT**

```
SELECT COL1||COL2||COL3 from TABLE_A
```

Becouse **I don't know the number and the name of the columns** in the table.

**Is it possible?**

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but `rownum='2'` will not work.

Comment: thanks. Yes I'ts an error :-p

Comment: Will all columns be `varchar` or `char`? If there are dates, in which format should they be displayed? Will there be `LOB`s?

Comment: They are different datatypes of different tables. I want a general procedure that works for all table. I can exclude CLOB.

Comment: You can use a combination of data dictionary(`ALL_TAB_COLS`) and dynamic sql to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try this, working for record with ID=1, you can change that, or add a loop if needed:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR CUR IS
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLE_A';
    STMT   VARCHAR(1000);
    RESULT VARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
    STMT := 'SELECT ';
    FOR COL in CUR
    LOOP
        STMT := STMT || COL.COLUMN_NAME || '||';
    END LOOP;
    STMT := STMT || ''''' FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID=1';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( STMT );
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        STMT
        INTO RESULT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'RESULT: ' || RESULT );
END;
```